# Trying to run zookeeper but running into directory issue?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Just want to preface this by saying its my first time using WSL, here are the steps that i have taken so far to get to the point i am at.

1. `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`
2. changed the config file to add the HOME path `export JAVA_HOME="/path/to/java8`
3. Downloaded latest binary file and unzipped the tar
4. Made a data directory and within that data directory created a folder called kafka and zookeeper
5. within zookeeper properties, add the relative path pointing to the datadir and add a `listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092`

Now here is where the problems occur when running `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` from the main directory, it comes up with the following error

```
/mnt/c/users/husse/downloads/kafka_2.13-3.6.1/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 346: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: cannot execute: Not a directory
```

Which essentially means i don't have the java 8 installed properly is what i'm guessing so i attempted to install the windows version then re-run the same command but the same problem came up

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys i'm actually so dumb, when adding to the home path, I added the full absolute path to where java is entered. So instead of the JAVA_HOME variable being this

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java`
it should've been

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Java 8 is end of life. Kafka doesn't need Zookeeper anymore. And it supports Java 17